# Why is my service not being started in Fragments onActivityResult?

Tags: android

In my fragment after a user signs in the onActivityResult callback is called.  I have logging in the onActivityResult and it is in fact being called but the service is not starting...  The service is registered in the Manifest and it gets executed in my onResume fine.  The getActivity is not returning NULL as well.  I do not know what the issue is... Can anyone give some advice.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_1:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyService.class);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
                getActivity().startService(intent);
            }
            break;
        default:

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need more printouts, put one after the case, and then after the if.

Comment: Do you have logs inside your Service, to confirm whether that is started?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem.

As @Justin pointed out in reply to me issue can be **registering properly** service in manifest file.

If you don't register app will crash. EXCEPT if you are using **IntentService**, which is by default in another thread so it will not crash your app but service  itself will.. It is just that we can't notice it, cause main activity UI will remain..

At the end I have typo in manifest declaring my IntentService class..

Hope somebody will find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you don't have the proper  tag registered in your manifest for your service.

To verify this, look at the `ComponentName` object being returned from `startService`. If it is null, no service is matching your intent.

Comment: what is the meaning of "no service is matching your itent" if there is a IntentService class named MyService?

Comment: If your service is not registered in AndroidManifest.xml, then Android will not be able to match your intent to your service to start it up. This is even the case when you target your service by name (which is what you did).

Answer (score -1):

I think you didnt declare you activity name in android manifest
to declare activity name write following code in android menifest.xml file like this

```
<activity 
        android:name=".YourActivityName">   
</activity>
```